# How to start IDL

Tags: macos, terminal, idl, textwrangler

I manage to get this command in my MacBook Pro Terminal Window :

IDL>

I am now in Text Wrangler. I type in print, "Hello World "

How do I get the words "Hello World" to appear in my MacBook Pro Terminal Window, from TextWrangler ? Do I have to save the file first ? What extension should I save it with ? Where would I save it ?

Thanks,
Tze

Answer (score 0):

Easiest method:

1. Save your file as "hello_world.pro".
2. Start IDL from the same directory as the "hello_world.pro" file or do:

   ```
    IDL> cd, 'directory/hello/world/is/in'
   ```
3. At the IDL prompt:

   ```
    IDL> hello_world
    Hello World
   ```

Eventually you will want to learn about `!path`, which will allow IDL to find your routines even if you are not in the same directory as the file.

Answer (score 0):

You could have this in a script hello.pro

```
a='Hello'
b='World'
print,a
print,b

end
```

Then call:

IDL> .r hello

And it will print:

Hello

World

and a and b will still be active variables on the command line. .run scripts are very useful for starting programs.